# Auto Tooltip Validation in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Where the heck are these things coming from?  I like them, and I would like to leverage them elsewhere in my site.  It appears they only show when I do regular expression validation in model:

```
[Display(Name = "Residential")]
[RegularExpression(@"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]?[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]
public Byte? residentialExperience { get; set; }
```

[image]

```
<div class="editor-label row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.residentialExperience)
</div>
<div class="editor-field row">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.residentialExperience)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.residentialExperience)
</div>
```

How can I use these validation tooltips elsewhere?  Also, how can I turn them off?

**Also:**  It's not displaying the same message as I have in my model.  It says, "Please enter a number" whereas I have written "Must be a number."

Comment: Interesting, same happen to me, but the funny part is that MVC's ModelState Validation was kicking in on an Int16 field over my custom validation attributes, but after 36 characters, this HTML validation also kicked in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are outputting a numeric field. If you look at your HTML you will see that you have something like this:

```
<input type="number" ... />
```

By defining the type as a numbber, the browser knows what to expect and it will give you a generic message. This is part of Html 5 spec.

If you want to override the default behavior you could do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.residentialExperience, new { @type = "text" })
```

Comment: HTML5...  I see, so how can I turn this off and display my default MVC error message?  This is cool but if I can't use it else where then it doesn't go with the rest of my application and may confuse the user.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a way to override the default behavior

Comment: Here is a short article that i found, but I do not think that I will implement html 5 validation. Might be good for simple things, but not when it comes to ensure you have valid data for important fields. [link](http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/)